# Error: The style prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string when onUploadProgress axios React

Tags: reactjs, axios

i have a redux action to upload image

```
const uploadDokumen = (file) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const data = new FormData()

        data.append('file', file)
        data.append('upload_preset', 'xxxxxx')
        data.append('cloud_name', 'xxxxxxx')

        const postDataDokumen = await CloudinaryAPI({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/image/upload',
            data: data,
            onUploadProgress: (data) => {
                let progress = Math.round((data.loaded * 100) / data.total)
                dispatch(setImageProgress(progress))
            }
        })

        dispatch(setUrlDokumen(postDataDokumen.data.url))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.response)
    }
}
```

but when i trigger this action, it return error

```
Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.
```

the error refers to dispatch `dispatch(setImageProgress(progress))`

need your help, i dont know what happened

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check your html code where style props are declared.
For i.e:

- Try adding {} to style props.
- Try removing "" from style props.